# How can I determine the rainbow book color of a CD on Linux?

Tags: linux, removable-storage

I have put a CD into my drive. How can I find the [rainbow book](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Books) color on Linux (Red book/Yellow book/Blue book/...)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `cd-info` from [the libcdio project](https://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/). This will list all your CD’s tracks, and for each one, give you information about its contents: CD-DA (red book), Photo CD (beige), Video CD (white), etc.

Comment: Take a look at this answer. He says all CDs are red books. Does this mean a CD can be a red book and a white book at the same time? https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/25977/25365

Comment: @zomega The later standards are extensions of the original one. I don't think any of them specifies what it means to say "CD is a red book".

Comment: @zomega: That is not what the answer says. It says that the Red Book is the standard that defines what a CD physically is. It does not say that CDs are red books.

Comment: @zomega As the answer says, the tool will give you the details for each track. So the basic CD itself is red book, but then the contents on it may be red book (because it's just a basic audio track), or it could be other kinds of formats from the various books.

Comment: @jcaron So the answer is yes (a CD can be a red book and a white book at the same time)?